# Should a photo gallery be in a post or on a page?

Tags: posts, gallery, pages, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I'm in the process of converting a legacy website (i.e., one that I programmed from scratch) into WordPress. The contents are mostly blog postings. I'm trying to figure out what to do with the non-blog stuff. In particular, the photo galleries. I'm using the NextGen Gallery plugin to manage my photos. Each photo gallery has several paragraphs of text.

Should a photo gallery be in a post or on a page?

Putting a photo gallery into a post relatively straight forward, with a general category (i.e., Picture) and a specific subcategory (i.e., 2004) for organization. For bigger photo galleries, it seems like I have to split them up over multiple posts to avoid saturating a post.

Putting a photo gallery into a individual page is similar to post. The problem is creating the overview page (i.e., Pictures) that points to the subpage (i.e., 2004) that points to the individual pages. I'm not sure how to connect all these pages without being more work than necessary.

Comment: You can use albums for this! And you can manage from Nextgen Gallery

Comment: "Should a photo gallery be in a post or on a page?" - A page definately. Whether it be you posting images into a single page or attaching a page template that pulls in images, a page just fits the task alot better.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Categories + Posts, if there's no data in-between that gets in the way.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the purpose of your gallery.

If you're writing a blog about your holidays, then it is appropriate to put "my day in Oxford" in a post.

If, on the other hand, you are using your gallery to show a piece of work, for example, then you may want to put it on a page.

The question is more to do with how you manage your content in general : the information you put on pages and that which you put into posts.

Perhaps the answer is in the purpose of the photos : if the objective is professional, then you may want to go for pages, if it is personal - you're sharing some images with friends as you meander through life - then posts would be the way to go.